# Можно ли создать указатель на функцию с неопределенными параметрами? c++

Tags: c++

Есть абстрактный класс в котором реализован шаблон использования метода возвращающего определенное значение, но параметры этого метода разные при различных реализациях класса, можно ли сохранять очередь (хотябы одну переменную) из указателей на функции с неопредленными параметрами в них?

```
class A {
  int (*func)(?);
  
  void F() {
    func(?)
  }
};

class B : public A {
  int v_func(int ptr) { std::cout << ptr << std::endl; }
  B {
    func = v_func;
  }
}
```

Comment: `std::any` в качестве параметра?

Comment: Шаблон можно использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Язык Си типизированный язык. Это значит функция должна быть вызвана на один тип.

Есть вариант создания классов, представляющих любые типы аргументов. Создаём абстрактный класс аргументов. Далее любые варианты как родственные классы от абстрактного. Типы аргументов сами функции должны преобразовывать под собственный класс.

Выкладываю два варианта.

```
// g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++11 absargs.cpp -o absargs
# include <iostream>
class AbsArgs {
public  :
virtual ~ AbsArgs(){}
} ;

class A {
public :
  int (A::*func)(AbsArgs & );
  int F(AbsArgs & arg) {    
    return  (this ->* func ) ( arg ) ;
  }
  virtual ~ A(){}
} ;

class BArgs : public  AbsArgs {
public  :
  int ptr ;
  BArgs(int x):ptr{x}{}
  virtual ~ BArgs(){}
} ;

class CArgs : public  AbsArgs {
public  :
  double number ;
  std :: string name ;
  CArgs(double d,std::string const & s):number{d},name{s}{}
  virtual ~ CArgs(){}
} ;

class B : public A {
public :
  int v_func(AbsArgs & arg) {
    if(typeid(arg) == typeid(BArgs)) {
      std::cout << "B(B) : " << static_cast<BArgs&>(arg).ptr << std::endl;
      ++  static_cast<BArgs&>(arg).ptr  ;
      return static_cast<BArgs&>(arg).ptr ; }
    if(typeid(arg) == typeid(CArgs)) {
      std::cout << "B(C) : "<< static_cast<CArgs&>(arg).number <<
      " " << static_cast<CArgs&>(arg).name <<
      std::endl;
      ++  static_cast<CArgs&>(arg).number ;
      return 0 ; }
    if(typeid(arg) == typeid(AbsArgs)) {
      std::cout << "B(Abs) : no arguments" << std::endl;
      return 0 ; }
    throw ; }
  B() {
    func = static_cast<int (A::*)(AbsArgs & )>(& B::v_func);
  }
  virtual ~ B(){}
} ;

class C : public A {
public :
  int v_func(AbsArgs & arg) {
    if(typeid(arg) == typeid(BArgs)) {
      std::cout << "C(B) : " << static_cast<BArgs&>(arg).ptr << std::endl;
      --  static_cast<BArgs&>(arg).ptr  ;
      return static_cast<BArgs&>(arg).ptr ; }
    if(typeid(arg) == typeid(CArgs)) {
      std::cout << "C(C) : "<< static_cast<CArgs&>(arg).number <<
      " " << static_cast<CArgs&>(arg).name <<
      std::endl;
      --  static_cast<CArgs&>(arg).number ;
      return 0 ; }
    if(typeid(arg) == typeid(AbsArgs)) {
      std::cout << "C(Abs) : no arguments" << std::endl;
      return 0 ; }
    throw ; }
  C() {
    func = static_cast<int (A::*)(AbsArgs & )>(& C::v_func);
  }
  virtual ~ C(){}
} ;

int main (  ) {
  A * a [ 2 ] ;
  a [ 0 ] = new B ;
  a [ 1 ] = new C ;
  AbsArgs aa  ;
  BArgs ba { 7 } ;
  CArgs ca { 3.1 , "name" } ;
  a [ 0 ] -> F ( aa ) ;
  a [ 0 ] -> F ( ba ) ;
  a [ 0 ] -> F ( ca ) ;
  a [ 1 ] -> F ( aa ) ;
  a [ 1 ] -> F ( ba ) ;
  a [ 1 ] -> F ( ca ) ;
  delete a [ 1 ] ;
  delete a [ 0 ] ;
}
```

проверка :

```
$ ./absargs 
B(Abs) : no arguments
B(B) : 7
B(C) : 3.1 name
C(Abs) : no arguments
C(B) : 8
C(C) : 4.1 name
```

Достоинством служит богатые возможности передачи разных аргументов. Ускорение компиляции из-за скрытия типов аргументов. Сами аргументы имеют область видимости **после** выполнения метода.

*Недостаток* : в стеке добавляется запись тип аргументов.

Comment: Проще передавать `void *` а внутри функций его приводить к типу действительному для вызываемой функции.

Comment: Строго говоря, вы сделали не вызов функции с любыми аргументами, а "любые" аргументы привели к одному типу.

Comment: Вопрос и был именно в этом. Как одному типу функций назначить функции с разными аргументами. Ваше предложение по-поводу `void*` будет работать, но будет невозможно контролировать ошибки несоотвествия типов. И не будет вариантов типов аргументов. А класс аргументов позволяет для одной функции имет дополнительные варианты набора аргументов. @Stanislav Volodarskiy

Comment: `dynamic_cast == run-time type identification, RTTI` https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Динамическая_идентификация_типа_данных @Stanislav Volodarskiy Про множественное наследование поищу ...

Comment: Я ошибся. `dynamic_cast` опирается RTTI (иногда компилятор обрабатывает его даже если RTTI отключен, но это значит что его можно вообще не писать). Прошу прощения.

Comment: Я ошибся. static_cast никогда не сломается (это `reinterpet_cast` сломается). Компилятор проверяет что имеет достаточно информации об обоих типах прежде чем скомпилировать `static_cast`.

Answer (score 1):

**Нет, нельзя.**

А если бы было можно, то как вы вызовете функцию в методе `F`. Ей нужны параметры. Какие ей нужны параметры знает только сама функция. Но и функция `F` тоже должна знать параметры. В конце концов параметры - это контракт между вызывающим кодом и вызываемой функцией.

Так вот, функцию `F` вы уже написали и откомпилировали. Значить контракт зафиксирован и можно вызывать только функции определённого типа.

**Да, немножко можно.**

Вы можете сделать функции с аргументом `void *`. Передавать в такую функцию можно указатель на объект любого типа, она сама будет приводить указатели. Так устроена [qsort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) в C и C++. Обратите внимание на объявление функции для сравнения элементов массива при сортировке: `int (*comp)(const void *, const void *)`. Вот пример такой функции. Она принимает два аргумента тип которых неизвестен в момент вызова:

```
int comp_ints(const void* a, const void* b) {
    int arg1 = *(const int*)a;
    int arg2 = *(const int*)b;
    ...
```

Программист отвечает за совпадение типов, компилятор ему не может помочь: все проверки типов выключены.

Кроме `void *` можно использовать `BaseClass *` (в классе должны быть виртуальные методы). Вызываемая функция будет делать `dynamic_cast`:

```
void f(BaseClass *obj) {
    DerivedClass *obj2 = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass *>(obj);
    if (obj2 != nullptr) {
    ...
```

Чуть больше помощи со стороны контроля типов, но ответственность всё равно на программисте.

В C++ есть шаблоны. Полный контроль типов. Работает так: шаблон пишется заранее, компилируется в промежуточную форму. Когда становятся известны типы аргументов вызываемой функции, шаблон инстанцируется (докомпилируется) в окончательный код.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` - будет работать **только** в присутсвии таблицы виртуальных функций класса `BaseClass`. **И** только при наследовании `public`. Обязательно нужно предупреждать о виртуальных функциях.

Comment: Покажите рабочий код с шаблонами.

Comment: Функция `decorate` не знает аргументов вызываемых функций. Но она может их передать в вызываемую функцию: [decorate.cpp](https://gist.github.com/StanislavVolodarskiy/278a872f17434b4f93a0b64296005886).

Comment: Не могу придумать чем помогут шаблоны. В вашем примере созданы три шаблонных функций `decorate<>` *(В стандарте это появилось только в C++14, а в Си это было от рождения используя* `# define fun()` *)* Они запускают три разных функции с разными аргументами. А вопрос был такой : "можно ли сохранять очередь (хотя бы одну переменную) из указателей на функции с неопределёнными параметрами в них?" Как вы сделаете очередь шаблонных функций никак не пойму.

Comment: `std::tuple` - пример разнородного контейнера в C++. Вот туда можно поместить три функции, а затем вызывать оборачивая в декоратор. Я понимаю что вы говорите:  шаблоны позволяют только compile-time polymorphism, но не run-time.